# Handling names in IDAPython

Tags: disassembly, ida

I am working on a small IDAPython script.

The script itself works 100% of the time on lines like this:

`qword_FFFFFFF006F1E6C0 DCQ 0xFFFFFFF007758C18`

As it looks into address `0xFFFF..` sees if there's a function there, and if there is, renames the qword with the function name + segment info.

Now, sometimes, the disassembly looks like this:

`off_FFFFFFF006F1E690 DCQ OSDictionary::withCapacity(uint)` , and of course, the script breaks down here (expects an address, is given a name..).

What I'd like to do is to get the address of the second operand (`OSDictionary::with...`), and execute the script as normal.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that, as to get the address I use this:

```
disas = GetDisasm(addr).split(" ")
fun_addr = disas[1]
....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the address of the destination, you could use get_qword function

https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1321.shtml

Which is the Qword function in IDAPython.
Simply do `Qword(addr)`, this will give you the address as a number. 
You might need to compensate for endianity (use struct).